# Emit Node.js Push Event from c# code behind

Tags: c#, node.js, web-services, .net-4.0, socket.io

I have a Node.js Http Server and Socket.IO running for my web app keeping all the clients in sync in real time.  I'm pushing node events out from the client and from the node server, both broadcasts and to individual "rooms".  This stuff is amazing.

Now, I have a use case where I would like to emit out a node.js event with a few params from c# code behind, inside a web service call.

```
[WebMethod] 
public MyMethod() 
{ 
    // emit node.js event
}
```

I thought about having a simple html page that requests querystring params and has node initialized in it.  And c# code behind just does a http web request calling the url with the params?  Not sure if that will work or be efficient, but first idea off the top of my head.

Any ideas or recommendations how to approach this one?  Currently, I'm limited to .NET 4.0

Comment: Where does this C# code reside, on the client or the server?

Comment: This C# code for the web service resides on the middleware server.

Comment: I usually associate "Code behind" with the event handlers that operate behind the scenes in an ASP.NET web page or other UI framework.  What is the context of "code behind" here?

Comment: This web service code behind is for...  
[WebMethod] 
public MyMethod() 
{ //run code here }

Comment: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/ ... although that may work in the opposite direction only.

Comment: This middleware web service method is called by our IVR system and updates the database.  After the database update, I'd like to emit out a node event to the user (receiving the call from the IVR) and update their screen in real time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18861687

Comment: Edge looks interesting... but requires .NET 4.5.  I'm currently limited to .NET 4.0.  Any more native approaches you can think of?